# How to query with day and time field?

Tags: mysql

I have table with fields:

- day (varchar)
- timeFrom (time)

I have this record already

[image: Table Result]

I need to find records that are less than tomorrow. But my query is giving empty result.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table as b
WHERE
    AND
    (
        b.`day` >= '2021-08-24' and b.time_from > '11:15:00' 
    )
```

Comment: And what's your quesiton about this? As far as I see, the record should **not** be returned as `time_from` is not greater than `11:15:00` in the given row

Answer (score 1):

You need to merge & cast your fields to build a datetime value, then you can use it in your `where` part or datetime functions:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `table` AS b
WHERE cast(concat(b.`day`, ' ', b.time_from) AS datetime) > '2021-08-24 17:30:00'
```

This query should work.

Answer (score 0):

you should add one day t now() function, then convert it to string and then compare it by you day filed.

Hope to help:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE day < DATE_FORMAT(date_add(now(), interval 1 day)
```

Comment: His `day` field is `varchar` hence need to cast it to `date` to use in datetime functions.

Comment: @endo64: No, not need to be cast, (Now() + 1day) function caste  to string.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion  you cannot use a ">" operator between strings (varchars)
I think the solution will be to modify the table structure from varchar to datetime.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What makes you think that there are any varchars used in the given query? How would you write a query with a date otherwise?